# Break statement doesn't work in loop (gcc)

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm sorta having a problem with my code. The function will not terminate and it keeps looping forever. I'm kinda new when it comes to compiling C in Linux (I came from Dev-C++..)

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

struct student{
    char lname[20];
    char fname[20];
    int idnum[8];
    int year;   
};

struct course{
    char cname[4];
    struct student stud[MAX];   
};


int main()
{   
    struct course c[0];

    userSelect(&c);
    return 0;
}

int userSelect(struct course *p_course)
{
    int z=0, x;
    printf("1 - Create course\n2 - Edit course\n3 - Add student(s)\n4 - Edit student data\n5 - Delete\n6 - Quit");
    scanf("\n%d", &x);
    while(z==0){
        switch(x){
            ccase 1: userCreateCourse(p_course);
            break;
            //case 2: userEditCourse(&c);
            //break;
            //case 3: userCreateStudents(&c);
            //break;
            //case 4: userEditStudents(&c);
            //break;
            case 6: printf("bye");
            z++;
            break;
            default: printf("Invalid input");
            break;
        }   
    }
}

int userCreateCourse(struct course *p_course)
{
    int *cnum=0, i;

    cnum=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    cnum++; 
    printf("Enter course (ex: BSCS): ");
    fgets(p_course[*cnum-1].cname, sizeof(p_course[*cnum-1]), stdin);
    puts(p_course[*cnum-1].cname);
}
```

If I select 1, this is the output:

```
1 - Create course
2 - Edit course
3 - Add student(s)
4 - Edit student data
5 - Delete
6 - Quit1

Enter course (ex: BSCS): H��4k


Enter course (ex: BSCS): AAAA

AAAA


Enter course (ex: BSCS): AAAA

AAAA

Enter course (ex: BSCS):
```

and it keeps doing that endlessly until I close the terminal. I really don't know what's wrong.. Someone help :(

Comment: Don't write code like this `case 6: printf("bye");z++;break;` it's horrible. Hard to read and ugly. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I was in a rush when I made the switch statement. I will edit it now.

Comment: `case 6: printf("bye");z++;break;` is not executed at all. So z value is always 0.

Comment: @Nari: What you are doing with that `cnum` variable is hilarious. That will probably be your next SO question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm still in my first year.. I know I suck :/

Comment: @Nari: I don't know how you arrived at that code but it is terribly broken and needs to be rethought. You are leaking allocated memory, the pointed-to memory is uninitialized, and I don't see a reason to use `malloc` in the first place.

Comment: @blastfurnace hmm well what I wanted to do is to keep track of the `cnum` so that i wont overwrite input when I leave the function. Buuut idk I'm just a newbie. I should put free(); somewhere..

Comment: @Nari: If you want `cnum` to have a longer lifespan than one function call there are options like declaring it `static`, making it a global variable, maybe make it a parameter passed by reference, etc.

Comment: @blastfurnace OH! Okay that'll work. Thank you for your feedback. I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read `x` *inside the loop*. What happens is that `x` remains the same value that you inputted the very first time. So `case 1:` is always executed.

---

You can use a do-while loop like:

```
do{
printf("1 - Create course\n2 - Edit course\n3 - Add student(s)\n4 - Edit student data\n5 - Delete\n6 - Quit\n");
scanf("\n%d", &x);

    switch(x){
        case 1: userCreateCourse(p_course);break;
        //case 2: userEditCourse(&c);break;
        //case 3: userCreateStudents(&c);break;
        //case 4: userEditStudents(&c);break;
        case 6: printf("bye");z++;break;
        default: printf("Invalid input");break;
    }
} while( z==0);
```

But remember there are a  number of issues with the `scanf()` + `fgets()` approach.

- The `scanf()` that reads `x` will leave a newline in the input buffer and `fgets()` will return immediately without reading input (due to `\n`).
  You can handle this by discarding any input chars left in the input with:

.

```
int c;  
while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF);
```

(just before `fgets()` call).

- If you input non-numbers input for `x`, then you'll end up with an infinite loop since `scanf()` doesn't ignore invalid input(s). You should check the scanf() return value and discard (using getchar() as above) all input chars if it failed.

Comment: OH! I didn't put the scanf statement in the loop! Oh my gosh I feel so dumb right now..

Comment: Well now the problem is that it doesn't stop to ask me for an input. It skips fgets and prints a garbage string D:

Comment: See the update for why. I suggest you read `x` too with `fgets()` to read a line and then use `sscanf()` to read `x`.

Comment: can I use `fflush(stdin);` ?

Comment: @Nari `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined* in C. It works on some platforms (such as windows) but I suggest you avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask for a new `x` inside the `while` loop if you want to be able to input a new one. Otherwise the first `x` will be used time and again since you never exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well it does breaks but it comes back again in your loop since `z == 0` remains `true`. It breaks out of your switch case, not out of your loop. At the end of the switch you should change the value of `z` for something different than `0` like :

```
while(z==0){
    switch(x){
        case 1: userCreateCourse(p_course);break;
        //case 2: userEditCourse(&c);break;
        //case 3: userCreateStudents(&c);break;
        //case 4: userEditStudents(&c);break;
        case 6: printf("bye");z++;break;
        default: printf("Invalid input");break;
    }   
    z = 1;
}
```

It'd be best for you to use a `boolean` like

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done){
   switch(smth){
      // do smth
   }
   done = true
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop is pointless if you have `z = 1` at the bottom.